# Encrypting a stream that terminates abruptly

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt a stdout stream to a file located on a removable drive.

However, as the drive can be removed at an arbitrary time, I am wondering how to manage this?

I have tried using openssl and a 256-bit AES cipher but unsurprisingly I get block length errors on the decrypt.

My bash scripts do this:

Encrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass file:"$KEY_FILE"
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pass file:"$KEY_FILE"
```

Unfortunately I'm on an embedded system so not many binaries included beyond what is necessary.  Bash and openssl are present however.

Comment: You have no choice but force synchronous writes to the removable media. and send the smallest valid packets. Anyway, removable storage media like USB connected that don't notify the host before actual removal or where host can decide to accept delay or deny removal, all expose the same data corruption risk.

Comment: Best option is to slice your data into small chunks and encrypt each chunks individually. If a chunk is incomplete and can not decide, you have at least preceding chunks valid.